# Get a block type of a page Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I would like to know how to find the block type of some page example : the home page.

I have a problem in my homepage, I want to display some block, in the xml I declared my block in `<cms_index_index>` (local.xml) but if I put it in the `<reference name="head">` it appears, if `<reference name="content">` or `<reference name="content">` it does not work . It seems to me that the type of block is not good.

xml:

```
<cms_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="seconnecter_test" template="customer/form/test-seconnecter.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

in the homepage 1column-full.phtml i called it like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('seconnecter_test');?>
```

i have tested to add `output="toHtml"`, it works but it displays me the block at the bottom of a footer, i want to display it in the place where i called `getChildHtml`.

Comment: provide your phtml code

Comment: i have found a solution, i called my block as getBlockhtml('seconnecter_test') and it works, i dont know why getChildHtml dont work !

Answer (score 0):

please add xml as below in `local.xml`

```
<cms_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="seconnecter_test" template="customer/form/test-seconnecter.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Select template for your home page `1column-full.phtml`

FYI: `type` in block tag is block class, if it's `core/template` then `Mage_Core_Block_Template`

Comment: it will add the block to the bottom of the content because 'content' is core/text_list block. replace content with root and it should work.

Comment: <reference name="content"> and <reference name="root"> doesn't work but <reference name="head"> work but i dont want to dsplay it in header. 
output="toHtml" display it at the bottom with reference="root", i tryed to move it at the top with before="content" but its not working

Answer (score 0):

If you know about block type, please check bellow the example for how to find proper block type.

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="modulename/blockname" name="seconnecter_test" template="customer/form/test-seconnecter.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

in this example, if you need specific block file for calling phtml in any page then check this, `modulename/blockname` so you find this block in your custom module path `Namespace_Modulename_Block_Blockname`.

if you used `core/templete` then this core template so you can call any phtml file using core block type.